# Wanning :Cannot merge cells

Tags: java

Estou com problema em um sistema de geração de formulários, quando passa de uma determinada aparece

> Warning: Cannot merge cells - top left and bottom right incorrectly specified

```
Range r = s.mergeCells(1, 0, total, 0); //<---quando passa dessa linha aparece o erro

Label alunos = new Label(1, 0, "QUANTIDADE DE ALUNOS", cf); 
s.addCell(alunos);

Label nome= new Label(total + 1, 0, "nome", cf);

s.addCell(nome);

s.mergeCells(total + 1, 0, total + 10, 0);

Label tabulacao = new Label(0, 0, "ASPECTOS", cf);

s.addCell(tabulacao);
```

Comment: Isso é java mesmo?

Comment: Sim, o sistema está utilizando a jexcelapi